# Text Tab Locking

Tags: docusignapi

My application has workflow that defines all of the content needed to sign a document on the DocuSign platform aside from signatures.  I'm using a parameter in my text tabs to ensure that values can only be edited within my application and workflow:

```
tabs: {
  textTabs: [
    {
      name: 'Name',
      tabLabel: '\\*Label',
      value: 'foo',
      locked: true
    }
  ]
}
```

When the value of the tab has no content provided, it becomes an editable field on the platform during signing; is there a way to prohibit modification of a tab entirely?  It is my preference that only signatures can be provided and the remainder of the document is left uneditable.

Comment: Haven't had time to test so not sure if that's a bug or not, or perhaps even as designed as it's weird that you have an empty locked field. As a small hack what happens if you provide something like a single space ( ) character as the value, is it locked in that case?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce what you are seeing. I create an envelope with a textTab and a signHereTab and am unable to  edit the text tab.

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

1. If the text tab is blank, and you do not want a recipient to enter information into the tab do not include it when creating your envelope
2. You can specify the locked=true property. The tab itself will not be visible to a signer if it is locked=true and empty.